# Краткий перевод слова backup

Tags: переводы

Можно ли достаточно кратко перевести на русский язык слово backup? На ум приходят только резервирование и копирование, но они, на мой взгляд, не полностью передают смысл, да и длинноваты всё равно.

Снимок окна программы: [image: снимок окна]

*PS. Ограничение связано с тем, что перевод делается для программы и место для текста ограничено*

Comment: Архив(ация)? Тоже немного не то, но, во-первых, такой перевод я уже где-то видел, возможно со времен Windows 95, а, во-вторых, более кратко все равно не сделаете.

Comment: Кстати, очень интересный вариант. Правда, если верить русской википедии, то архивация — процесс создания архива для хранения, а резервное копирование — для восстановления.

Comment: А "Резервировать" тоже слишком длинно? Вполне вроде неплохой вариант. Или просто "Резерв". "Создать резерв".

Comment: Резервировать — в принципе подходит по длине, но мне кажется, что оно несколько искажает смысл, да и хотелось бы, чтобы пункт меню назывался "Резервирование", а не "Резервировать". А "Резервирование" уже не умещается.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Резервное копирование. Именно так. Короче не получается. 
Или оставляйте без перевода. Термин устоявшийся и почти вошедший в общеупотребительный язык.

А что за программулина такая, что так прихотлива к размеру сообщений? Лет пятнадцать о таком не слышал, с тех пор как перестали вбивать русский текст в двоичный код.

Или это что-то для мобильных платформ?

~~~~ 22.08.2012

Рассмотрел я, наконец, эту штуку.
Здесь подойдет только ***"сохранить(ся)"***. Когда-то давным-давно, во времена первых IBMок был ешё термин *"спасти"*, как прямой перевод *"save"*, но это давно в прошлом.

Comment: К сожалению, резервное копирование никак не уместится. 

Тут же возник вопрос насчет того, как оставить без перевода — если перевести (транскрибировать) как бэкап/бекап, то, мне кажется, такой вариант будет выглядеть слишком "слэногово". Но и оставить просто "backup" тоже выглядит не лучшей идеей. В общем, я весь в сомнениях.

Comment: Программа называется crashplan (не сочтите за рекламу :) ). Проблема в том, что в левой части программы ( http://i.imgur.com/LnKqI.png ) имеется меню, которое сильно расширять не хотелось бы.

Comment: ответил в основном тексте

Comment: Очень интересный вариант - "сохранение" и "загрузка". Думаю, новых интересных ответов уже не будет, так что закрываю вопрос.

Спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 2):

> И вот крестьянам под страхом расстрела предлагалось устраивать под домами так называемые «**[схроны](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%81%D1%85%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD)**», складывать в них хлеб, все имущество и прятаться самим; устраивались «схроны» даже для скота.

Д. Н. Медведев, «Сильные духом (Это было под Ровно)», 1948 г.

Comment: Вряд ли. "Схрон" имеет вполне конкретное значение, далекое от "резервная копия"

Comment: Это на случай, если требование по символам ограничивает здравый смысл. Зато на один символ короче, чем английский вариант.